# Handling and waiting for previous JavaScript calls to complete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, listener, dom-events

I have a function that is bound to mouse click events on a Google Map. Due to the nature of the function it can take a few moments for processing to complete (.1sec - 2sec depending on connection speeds). In itself this is not much of a problem, however if the user gets click happy, this can cause problems and later calls are a bit depended on the previous one.

What would be the best way to have the later calls wait for previous ones to complete? Or even the best way to handle failures of previous calls?

I have looked at doing the following:

- Using a custom `.addEventListener` [(Link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)
- Using a while loop that waits previous one has processed
- Using a simple if statement that checks if previous one needs to be re-run
- Using other forms of callbacks

Now for some sample code for context:

```
this.createPath = function(){
    //if previous path segment has no length
    if (pathSegment[this.index-1].getPath().length === 0){ 
        //we need the previous path segment recreated using this same function
        pathSegment[this.index-1].createPath();
        //now we can retry this path segment again
        this.createPath();
    }
    //all is well, create this path segment using Google Maps direction service
    else {
        child.createPathLine(pathSegment[this.index-1].getEndPoint(), this.clickCoords);
    }
}
```

Naturally this code as it is would loop like crazy and create many requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for *promises*.

They work like this (example using jQuery promises, but there are other APIs for promises if you don't want to use jQuery):

```
function doCallToGoogle() {
   var defer = $.Deferred();

   callToGoogleServicesThatTakesLong({callback: function(data) { 
        defer.resolve(data); 
   }});

   return defer.promise();
}

/* ... */
var responsePromise = doCallToGoogle();

/* later in your code, when you need to wait for the result */
responsePromise.done(function (data) {
     /* do something with the response */
});
```

The good thing is that you can chain promises:

```
var newPathPromise = previousPathPromise.then(
       function (previousPath) { /* build new path */ });
```

Take a look to:

- http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/
- http://api.jquery.com/promise/

To summarize promises are an object abstraction over the use of callbacks, that are very useful for control flow (chaining, waiting for all the callbacks, avoid lots of callback nesting).

Comment: Thanks Diego! I did some looking into these options, they seem promising. However I'm not seeing a easy way to build dependence on the completion of the previous request before the next runs. In the second part you mention the .then which I think I might be able to use. From the testing I did it looks like you can even tag on .then well after the promise has resolved. Perhaps make dummy resolved defer and queue using .then. Would that even make sense? It doesn't seem very clean to me.